# Help with Boundary Integral Equation Method with laplace equation (Given NURBS curve)

Tags: optimization, numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis

I am trying to use a boundary integral equation method to solve for laplace equation given the control points of a NURBS curve. But my BIEM is giving me very large error for numerical functions.

I first did an analytical example of a circle and it work perfectly with negligible error, but then when I moved on to do the Numerical part the solver gives very large error. I am working on with boundary function (x^2 - y^2)/(2 * pi) for both cases, and I have all my code listed below.

Can anyone help me identify the error？Thanks.
This is the analytical part:

```
N = 200
a = 1
b = 1
nxgrid = 100
nygrid = 100
xmin = -2.2
xmax = 2.2
ymin = -2.2
ymax = 2.2

theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N + 1)
theta = theta[:-1]

x = a * np.cos(theta)
y = b * np.sin(theta)

tx = -a * np.sin(theta)
ty = b * np.cos(theta)

ax = -a * np.cos(theta)
ay = -b * np.sin(theta)
nx = np.zeros(N)
ny = np.zeros(N)
w = np.zeros(N)

for i in range(N):
    nx[i] = ax[i] / np.sqrt(ax[i] ** 2 + ay[i] ** 2)
    ny[i] = ay[i] / np.sqrt(ax[i] ** 2 + ay[i] ** 2)
    h = 1 / (N) * 2 * np.pi
    w[i] = h * np.sqrt(tx[i] ** 2 + ty[i] ** 2)

f = (x**2 - y**2) / (2*np.pi)

K = np.zeros((N, N))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if i == j:
            kappa = (tx[j] * ax[j] - ty[j] * ay[j]) / (tx[j] ** 2 + ty[j] ** 2) ** 1.5
            kappa = 1
            K[i, j] = -kappa / (4 * np.pi) * w[j]
        else:
            dx = x[j] - x[i]
            dy = y[j] - y[i]
            dot = nx[j] * dx + ny[j] * dy
            r = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
            K[i, j] = dot / (2 * np.pi * r ** 2)
            K[i, j] = K[i, j] * w[j]

sigma = np.linalg.solve(-np.eye(N) / 2 + K, f)

xlin = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nxgrid)
ylin = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, nygrid)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)

u = np.zeros((nxgrid, nygrid))
for i in range(nxgrid):
    for j in range(nygrid):
        if (X[i, j] / a) ** 2 + (Y[i, j] / b) ** 2 >= 1:
            u[i, j] = np.nan
        else:
            u[i, j] = 0
        for k in range(N):
            dx = X[i, j] - x[k]
            dy = Y[i, j] - y[k]
            dot = nx[k] * dx + ny[k] * dy
            r = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
            u[i, j] = u[i, j] - dot / (2 * np.pi * r ** 2) * w[k] * sigma[k]     

plt.imshow(u)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This is the helper's function for the numerical part:

```
# Function to evaluate a curve at a given parameter t
def Z(t, curve):
    point = curve.evaluate_single(t)
    return point[:2]  # Discard the last coordinate (if 3D) 

# Function to calculate the derivative of a curve at a given parameter t
    def Z_derivative(t, curve):
    dpoint = curve.derivatives(t, order=1)
    return np.array(dpoint[1][:2])

# Function to calculate the second derivative of a curve at a given parameter t
def Z_2nd_derivative(t, curve):
    dpoint = curve.derivatives(t, order=2)
    return np.array(dpoint[2][:2])

# Function to determine whether a point is within the NURBS curve
def point_inside_curve(point, curve_points):
    x, y = point
    n = len(curve_points)
    inside = False

    p1x, p1y = curve_points[0]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        p2x, p2y = curve_points[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y, p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y, p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x, p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xinters = (y - p1y) * (p2x - p1x) / (p2y - p1y) + p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x, p1y = p2x, p2y

    return inside
```

and this is the numerical part:

```
N = 100

s_values = np.linspace(0, 1, N+1)
s_values = s_values[:-1]
crvpts = np.array([Z(t, curve) for t in s_values])

xmin = int(min(crvpts[:,0]))
xmax = int(max(crvpts[:,0]))
ymin = int(min(crvpts[:,1]))
ymax = int(max(crvpts[:,1]))
nxgrid = 300
nygrid = 300

x = [Z(s, curve)[0] for s in s_values]
y = [Z(s, curve)[1] for s in s_values]

tx = [Z_derivative(s, curve)[0] for s in s_values]
ty = [Z_derivative(s, curve)[1] for s in s_values]

ax = [Z_2nd_derivative(s, curve)[0] for s in s_values]
ay = [Z_2nd_derivative(s, curve)[1] for s in s_values]

nx = np.zeros(N)
ny = np.zeros(N)
w = np.zeros(N)

for i in range(N):
    nx[i] = ax[i] / np.sqrt(ax[i] ** 2 + ay[i] ** 2)
    ny[i] = ay[i] / np.sqrt(ax[i] ** 2 + ay[i] ** 2)
    h = 1 / (N)
    w[i] = h * np.sqrt(tx[i] ** 2 + ty[i] ** 2)

f = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    f[i] = (x[i]**2 - y[i]**2) / (2*np.pi)

K = np.zeros((N, N))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if i == j:
            kappa = (tx[j] * ax[j] - ty[j] * ay[j]) / (tx[j] ** 2 + ty[j] ** 2) ** 1.5
            kappa = 1
            K[i, j] = -kappa / (4 * np.pi) * w[j]
        else:
            dx = x[j] - x[i]
            dy = y[j] - y[i]
            dot = nx[j] * dx + ny[j] * dy
            r = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
            K[i, j] = dot / (2 * np.pi * r ** 2)
            K[i, j] = K[i, j] * w[j]

sigma = np.linalg.solve(-np.eye(N) / 2 + K, f)

xlin = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nxgrid)
ylin = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, nygrid)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlin, ylin)

u = np.zeros((nxgrid, nygrid))
for i in range(nxgrid):
    for j in range(nygrid):
        if not point_inside_curve([X[i,j], Y[i,j]], crvpts):
            u[i, j] = np.nan
        else:
            u[i, j] = 0
        for k in range(N):
            dx = X[i, j] - x[k]
            dy = Y[i, j] - y[k]
            dot = nx[k] * dx + ny[k] * dy
            r = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
            u[i, j] = u[i, j] - dot / (2 * np.pi * r ** 2) * w[k] * sigma[k]     

plt.imshow(u)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```